# Convert Marshal loaded string into object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I access session data which is stored in the database using Marshal:

```
<%= Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session.data)) %>
```

Which returns the following string:

```
{"_csrf_token"=>"G/l/RK08vhzy/jMCVfmBRpCQKA5IxiACd1e0pWqMlkA=", "user_id"=>1, "ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1", "browser"=>"Chrome on Macintosh 10.11.5"}
```

What I want to do is access the `ip_address` and `browser` directly so I can do something like:

```
<%= session.data[:ip_address] %>
```

How can I convert what `Marshal.load` returns into a usable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a string, it seems an hash. Try

```
<% my_session = Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session.data)) %>
<%= my_session['ip_address'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a hash, not a string, thus you can access it's key-value pairs using any of [Hash methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html).

Using [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) is your another option:

```
require 'ostruct'
h = {"_csrf_token"=>"G/l/RK08vhzy/jMCVfmBRpCQKA5IxiACd1e0pWqMlkA=", "user_id"=>1, "ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1", "browser"=>"Chrome on Macintosh 10.11.5"}
object = OpenStruct.new(h)
object.ip_address
#=> "127.0.0.1"
object.browser
#=> "Chrome on Macintosh 10.11.5"
```